# No 'tmp_name' being set when uploading utf-16 xml in a zip through php

Tags: php, xml, encoding

I'm relatively new to PHP and I'm creating an upload page for database reports. These reports automatically come as `utf-16` XML pages and can't be converted to `utf-8` on creation. The report comes with a summary page and the report page, which are then archived and submitted. The only issue is that every file uploads - apart from `utf-16` encoded files in a zip. The zip files don't seem to be getting set a `tmp_name`, but they do if the files are `utf-8` or any other file.
 My code is as follows:

```
$newfiles = array_filter($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$count= count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
echo $count
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
//Setup a temp filepath
 $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
  echo 'temp file path is set as ' . $tmpFilePath;
 //Make sure we have a filepath
 if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
 //Setup our new file path
 $destination_path = getcwd().'/ddr/';
 $target_path = $destination_path . basename( $_FILES['userfile'].    ['name'][$i]);

 //echo "hello";
 if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["userfile"]["name"] [$i]). "    has been uploaded to " . $target_path;
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file to " .   $target_path;
}
$uploadfiletype = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 if ($uploadfiletype = '.zip'){
  $zip = new ZipArchive;
  $res = $zip->open($target_path);
  if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo($destination_path);
    $zip->close();
    //echo 'ok';
    } else {
    echo 'failed';
    }
  } 
 }
}
```

My `echo 'temp file path is set as ' . $tmpFilePath;` just returns with out a `$tmpfilepath` value but `echo $count;` does return a value. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Edit: It's nothing to do with max upload size

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES); die();` and inspect the output

Comment: would ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }  indicate that tmp_name is not being set? I also get ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } so is it likely that the upload itself is failing?

Comment: seems the whole upload is not working correctly. use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` check error.log, ensure tmp folder is writable or uploaded file is exceeding limits for your post upload size

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski the error reporting is already set to all, and nothing is reporting (apart from syntax errors from constantly changing my code to try get around this) tmp is writable and i disabled the post upload size yesterday to try and get it to work - still no joy. Not entirely sure why it would allow me to upload other types of files (in zip format too). Do you know if there were any know issues with php 5.6?

Comment: You wrote `The zip files don't seem to be getting set a tmp_name, but they do if the files are utf-8 or any other file` - you mean filename is using utf-16? Because if not, then content is irrelevant as far as we talk about uploading or tmp_name. Further processing is another story but that's too far for now

Comment: The entire script works for archives containing utf-8 encoded xml files, or images, or documents of any type i've tried, just not utf-16 xml files. Even works for multiple files- still doesn't want to play ball with utf-16 xml.  The filename doesn't contain utf-16, the name i've been testing with is literally "Archive.zip" or Archive1.zip etc